# python 2.7 list: Clear content of a list using Del list method, also deletes previously archived copy of that list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Problem: 
Case-1 : If I append a sub_list in a main_list and delete sub_list using python 2.7 Del list method, it clear content of sub_list, But also clear sub_list content archived in main_list. Why ?

Case-2: I tried to use sub_list = []. Which is working fine.

I want to know why case 1 is NOK But case 2 is OK

Source Code:

```
sub_list = []
main_list = []
sub_list.append(1)
sub_list.append(2)
sub_list.append(3)
main_list.append(sub_list)
del sub_list[0:]
print(main_list)
```

I expect output to be [[1,2,3]] but output is [[]]

Comment: I expect you show your code. Downvote

Comment: Please add the code you mention you used in the question

Comment: assigning list to new variable doesn't duplicate list but it create "alias" to the same list. If you need two copies then you have to use `new_list = copy.deepcopy(old_list)` and then you can delete elements in old list and it will not delete elements in new list.

Comment: you can use portal [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/) to see how lists work. it will show references to list ("aliases") as arrows and you will see why it can delete elements in one list when you delete elements in another list.

Comment: `append()` doesn't copy elements from `sub_list` to `main_list`. It only append reference to `sub_list` so you still use the same list. Assigning `[]` doesn't delete elements so case 2 works correctly. If you run your code on [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/) then you will see how it works.

Comment: you can use list.extend so that it will do deep copy, the values of the main_list will be retained even after you delete the sub_list.
**main_list.extend(sub_list)**

Answer (score 1):

```
sub_list = []
main_list = []
sub_list.append(1)
sub_list.append(2)
sub_list.append(3)
main_list.extend(sub_list)
del sub_list[0:]
print(main_list)
```